# c++ semicolon - what are the rules for loops and statements?

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and generally it has good and clear rules - but I'm a little confused about the rules related to semicolon. The following two examples are working fine - but what is the best practice - and what is the logic behind it?

Example1 (without semicolon):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (true) {
            cout << i << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Example2 (with 3x semicolon):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (true) {
            cout << i << endl;
        };

    };
};
```

Comment: I recommend you pick up a nice C++ book which explains things like this in detail. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/10147399) list. I personally recommend [C++ Primer](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321714113). Good luck!

Comment: Semi-colons are a punctuator, they denote the end of a statement. The example you have shown are redundant uses of semi-colons.

Comment: Thanks a ton - I’ll get the book..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 2, reformatted:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (true) {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
        /*do nothing*/ ;
    }
    /*do nothing*/ ;
}
/*do nothing*/ ;
```

In other words, `;` in this case is simply an empty statement, totally superfluous. It's legal, but about as useful as the statement `42;`, which is *also* legal :-)

However, it can *sometimes* be useful in things like (one example of many), though I usually prefer the `{}` construct in these cases:

```cpp
while (performAction(var++)) ;
```